# Editing the grub.cfg file in Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, virtualbox

I'm new to Linux but I'm following this tutorial to build my own operating system:
[Write your own Operating System in 1 hour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rnA6wpF0o4&list=PLHh55M_Kq4OApWScZyPl5HhgsTJS9MZ6M&index=1)

at the end of the first video, I need to edit the grub.cfg file by adding the follwoing:

```
### BEGIN MY KERNEL ###
menuentry 'My Operating System'  
{
   multiboot /boot/mykernel.bin
   boot
}
### END MY KERNEL ###
```

It looks like it's [only for reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igfa7.png) on my virtual machine!

[image: readonly warning]

I want to complete the process, and see the output, how can I edit this file?

Answer (score 0):

The grub.cfg keeps updating on several changes like updating the grub, installing newer version of kernel, header images and replated stuffs. You should not change directly grub.cfg. `/etc/grub.d/`and your configured file(if not then `40_custom`) and add make your tweak there.

```
su root
nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Don't forget to apply settings by

```
update-grub
```

if that's not debian based distro then it is equivalent to

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109792/discussion-on-answer-by-sudip-ghimire-editing-the-grub-cfg-file-in-ubuntu-on-vir).